# how to make infragetics dock manager overlay other controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml, overlay

I'm using dock manager of Infragistics WPF controls. I have only one tab on it, which is at the bottom of window.I have other controls on the window. when user hover the mouse over the tab at the bottom of window , it suppose to open up (popup) over other controls in the window. but it only open up (height wise) until the upper controls let it to. I want to build something similar to dockable tabs in Visual Studio (solution explorer , Error List). you know to overlay on top of whatever controls I have in the main windowm but it doesn't work. any ideas?

btw I'm new to WPF. so I'm guessing it has something to do with layout controls I used and it's probably very simple.

here's the code :

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <c:RibbonWindow DockPanel.Dock="Top"></c:RibbonWindow> 
        <c:MessagePane DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"></c:MessagePane>
```

### the ribbon window is user control includes a stack panel contains ribbon control and other controls

here's the content user control called MessagePane :

```
<UserControl x:Class="LanguageLearningInstitute.Windows.MessagePane"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
                 xmlns:igDP="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
                 xmlns:igDock="http://infragistics.com/DockManager"
                 >
<Grid>
    <igDock:XamDockManager Name="dm">
        <igDock:XamDockManager.Panes>
            <igDock:SplitPane igDock:XamDockManager.InitialLocation="DockedBottom">
                <igDock:ContentPane x:Name="MessageList" Header="Error List" AllowClose="False" MinHeight="150" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" IsPinned="False">
                    <igDP:XamDataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dgv">
                         <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                              <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AllowDelete="False" AddNewRecordLocation="OnTopFixed" AllowAddNew="False"/>
                        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                    </igDP:XamDataGrid>
                </igDock:ContentPane>
            </igDock:SplitPane>
        </igDock:XamDockManager.Panes>
    </igDock:XamDockManager>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Take a look at Gemini https://github.com/tgjones/gemini.

Comment: I checked that. I'm in middle of a project. I can't change to that. and I looked into the solution and couldn't find how they solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and I'm putting it here in case anybody would ever com upon the same problem. I added my ribbon user control inside the dock manager control after the definition of panes.

```
<igDock:XamDockManager Name="dm">
        <igDock:XamDockManager.Panes>
            <igDock:SplitPane igDock:XamDockManager.InitialLocation="DockedBottom">
                <igDock:ContentPane x:Name="MessageList" Header="Error List" AllowClose="False" MinHeight="150" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" IsPinned="False">
                    <igDP:XamDataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dgv">
                         <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                              <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AllowDelete="False" AddNewRecordLocation="OnTopFixed" AllowAddNew="False"/>
                        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                    </igDP:XamDataGrid>
                </igDock:ContentPane>
            </igDock:SplitPane>
        </igDock:XamDockManager.Panes>
         <c:RibbonWindow></c:RibbonWindow>
    </igDock:XamDockManager>
```